# Ubuntu 22.04 fan speed / CPU performance too low

Tags: 22.04, performance, cpu, fan

My laptop (Dell Precision 7560, i7-11850H, Ubuntu 22.04, kernel 5.17) really felt sluggish, so I ran [Passmark](https://www.passmark.com/products/performancetest/download.php) and to my shock the results were abysmal.

Compared to [the average](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i7-11850H+%40+2.50GHz&id=4342), single threaded was only 1769 MOps instead of 3,193 MOps. Further tests reveal that the cpu boosts to ~3.8GHz for the first test, but then falls back to 2.5 GHz for the remaining tests. On the flipside, the fans never really spin up.

What I already tried:

- Installed latest bios
- set thermal management to "ultra-performance" in bios.
- set cpu-governor to 'performance' (sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor performance)
- set Power Mode to 'performance'

Nothing resolved the issue so far. Any ideas?

---

Output of `turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 15` while running benchmark

```
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
2.01    3846    33924   49  8.05    5.66    0.28    0.00
51.37   4294    50477   94  35.66   33.50   0.17    0.00
94.79   2656    63803   62  23.36   20.66   0.00    0.00
79.66   2500    57852   68  24.75   21.84   0.00    0.00
85.72   2500    72991   58  23.59   21.22   0.06    0.00
66.64   2499    47928   69  16.98   14.12   0.00    0.00
```

Comment: It could be thermal throttling and/or power limit throttling. One way to know is to run turbostat while you do your tests. Suggest: `sudo /home/doug/kernel/linux/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 15`

Comment: @DougSmythies I added results. The temps peak to 100C at the start and then drop to 60-70C. The issue is definitely the fans not spinning up.

Answer (score 3):

A colleague of mine who owns the same model was still on an old BIOS version (1.8.0) and it turns out BIOS 1.12.1 butchered the single thread performance. I ran some tests with multiple BIOS versions (note: one cannot downgrade below 1.10.1):

| bios | 1.8.0 | 1.10.1 | 1.11.0 | 1.12.1 | 1.14.0 | 1.17.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CPU Mark | 22799 | 21389 | 21716 | 16380 | 16642 | 15537 |
| Integer Math | 82197 | 80764 | 82160 | 81796 | 82121 | 82121 |
| Floating Point Math | 45573 | 40331 | 42812 | 37724 | 30572 | 24844 |
| Prime Numbers | 92.5 | 67.1 | 68.1 | 66 | 78.8 | 64.9 |
| Sorting | 35484 | 34472 | 35236 | 24022 | 24975 | 24269 |
| Encryption | 15686 | 15874 | 16106 | 10670 | 10676 | 10661 |
| Compression | 262098 | 278784 | 277925 | 184606 | 183600 | 184190 |
| CPU Single Threaded | 3253 | 3294 | 3289 | 1773 | 1770 | 1769 |
| Physics | 1086 | 722 | 728 | 701 | 1035 | 717 |
| Extended Instructions (SSE) | 15634 | 16181 | 16190 | 11667 | 11643 | 11670 |

One can very easily even hear the difference. With v1.8.0, v.1.10.1 v1.11.0, when running the benchmark the fans spin up a lot, after that they stay whisper quiet and the performance massively drops after the first benchmark (integer math) runs through.
Also, the performance for prime numbers and physics behaves weird.

---

All the tests above are when plugging directly into the 180W charger. When using battery or WD19TBS (130W) I got ~10% less performance. Crucially, the single thread seems to still be strong.

| operating mode (bios 1.10.1) | charger | battery | WD19TBS (lid open) | WD19TBS (lid closed) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CPU Mark: | 21389 | 19106 | 19270 | 18853 |
| Integer Math | 80764 | 66552 | 70546 | 68479 |
| Floating Point Math | 40331 | 34789 | 36843 | 35464 |
| Prime Numbers | 67.1 | 66.4 | 60.1 | 53.1 |
| Sorting | 34472 | 30714 | 31393 | 30497 |
| Encryption | 15874 | 14624 | 15549 | 15000 |
| Compression | 278784 | 239844 | 255046 | 247432 |
| CPU Single Threaded | 3294 | 3294 | 3110 | 3264 |
| Physics | 722 | 728 | 604 | 625 |
| Extended Instructions (SSE) | 16181 | 13127 | 14000 | 13927 |

Comment: I have the same issue. Would you say I'd be losing anything by downgrading to pre 1.12.1?

Comment: @The-Duck Mine seems to be running fine with 1.11.0 You can read detailed change logs on the dell support website. It seems to be mostly security.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and detailed report, will try and report back if I find any major issues.

Comment: @The-Duck Did you manage to reproduce the behavior? Is 1.12.1 also the version from which on the issue occurs? Also: does your 7560 happen to have a GPU? Dell support tried to reproduce the issue and say they couldn't reproduce it. The only difference is their machine had a  nvidia gpu and mine doesn't.

Comment: Not at all. Running 1.17.1 I have no single thread performance reduction. I have a few differences from you though. I do have a GPU and I am running Windows 10 (wouldn't expect this to effect Passmark CPU performance though). Personally, my issue is straight up over heating and the associated performance reduction due to it. I believe Dell's CPU/GPU active cooling is completely broken. My fans are barely if at all audible. (I checked, they are working fine separately). Will try have them swap the HW and see if that resolves anything. Might be a faulty temperature sensor.

Answer (score 0):

## Update Feb 2024

So, I accidentally had a bios update done by `fwupd` and cannot downgrade any longer. After lots of digging and looking around, **I found an absolutely horrifying workaround.**

The problem seems to be that dell locks down the fan control in bios, and somehow that fan control is not working properly. (The fans themselves are functional!) **It appears we can "trick" this bios fan control by switching the thermal profile every few seconds with `smbios`.**

Below I show this patch in action. A stress test has been running for some time. The CPU is throttled to the base clock of 2.5GHz @ 60°C. **The fans do absolutely nothing.** After switching the thermal profile, the CPU temporarily boosts and the fans start to turn up. By switching every 5 seconds, we can keep the boost clock running.

[image]

Shoutout to https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui for the great monitoring tool.

### ⚠️ NO WARRANTY ⚠️ NO LIABILITY ⚠️ **I have no clue if this constant switching has the potential to damage hardware. Use at your own risk!!** ⚠️

Create two files `/etc/systemd/system/dell_fan_patch.service` and `/etc/systemd/system/dell_fan_patch.timer` with content

```ini
[Unit]
Description=This job switches every few second the thermal profile via smbios-utils.

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'smbios-thermal-ctl --set-thermal-mode=balanced; sleep 5; smbios-thermal-ctl --set-thermal-mode=performance'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Timer for Updating Thermal Profile Every 5 Seconds

[Timer]
OnBootSec=30s
OnUnitActiveSec=10s
AccuracySec=1s
Unit=dell_fan_patch.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Enable via

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable dell_fan_patch.timer
sudo systemctl start dell_fan_patch.timer
```